# Check for particular value from class object and get the value of another key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, openstack

I have code implemented to reach the DB using CLI client.

I can be able to get the values as needed.

Consider the following code:

```
# Establish the connection Cloudkitty
ck = client.get_client(kwargs_conn.get('cloudkitty_version'), **kwargs_conn)

list_services = ck.hashmap.services.list()

for services in list_services:

        print services
        print(type(services))
```

It will produce the output as follows:

```
<hashmap.Service {u'service_id': u'2c6e0447-0cdb-4d12-8511-4544ba0d03b5', u'name': u'compute'}>
<class 'cloudkittyclient.v1.rating.hashmap.Service'>
<hashmap.Service {u'service_id': u'48297131-de33-48ad-b5b5-43d3a3177841', u'name': u'volume'}>
<class 'cloudkittyclient.v1.rating.hashmap.Service'>
```

Output being retuned is used to be a class object.

Now here I need to check for the returned object for particular value for the key. To be precise I want to check that whether it have the 'name' as 'compute', If yes I need to get the service_id of the same.

Someone let me know how we can achieve the same.

Library used : https://github.com/openstack/python-cloudkittyclient

Comment: What is `hashmap.Service`? Please add reference to the library you are using to get this.

Comment: Try a `print(dir(services))` to see the attributes. A debugger with GUI as it comes with an IDE will also be a help to see the insides of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some of [tests](https://github.com/openstack/python-cloudkittyclient/blob/55f3a3fa7568dec1d37db0a4960755f8460422a4/cloudkittyclient/tests/v1/test_hashmap.py#L441) in the library, it seems you can directly access the fields like `service_id`:

```
for service in list_services:
    if service.name == 'compute':
        print(service.service_id)
```

Or, if you want to get the service ids for all the services where name is `compute`:

```
service_ids = [service.service_id for service in list_services if service.name == 'compute']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if services.get("name") == "compute":
      id_ = services.get("service_id")

      #assuming li = [] declaration above you could add that to a list 
      # of IDs
      li.append(id_)
```

Note I am *assuming* from the prints above that the class is Dictionary-like in behavior.